# How to interrupt input

Tags: c, unix, io, pthreads

I am implementing a client which uses two threads: one that receives data from a server and prints it to stdout, the other one uses fgets to ask a string to the user and sends a message to the server.The threads are always in execution, but there is a problem: I don't know how to stop the thread that takes input from the user.I tried closing stdin with fclose, but the stream remains opened until the user digits a string.How is possible to close the input buffer in a way that fgets is interrupted?
I hope the question is clear.

Comment: How about non-blocking I/O and something like epoll?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A signal can interrupt an I/O operation. Assuming you didn't use the SA_RESTART flag for the sigaction signal handler, the read will return with an errno of EINTR.

Comment: is fgets guaranteed to return an error on EINTR, or could it just go silently back to reading?

Comment: Fair enough. I asked because EINTR is not, in general, an error: it just means your thread was used to execute a signal handler. In fact, none of the *NIX manpages I can find describe fgets failing with anything except EOF or EBADF

Comment: Unfortunately, glibc's fgets/getc retry on EINTR and can't be interrupted easily.